# React OpenLayers parent context

Tags: reactjs, openlayers

I have built an app that is working as I want it too (small sample here: https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/nvtss60h/).

Now though I need to break the component into more manageable/reusable components. At the moment I have a `<Map />` component with all of the logic taking place inside that one component.

What I would like to have is something like this (https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/47581h2m/):

```
<Map>
  <ScaleLine units="imperial" />
  <Layer source={...some-source...} />
</Map>
```

The problem I am running into is that in the example I need to access `this.map` on the parent component from the child component to add the Scale line.

Is there a way I can access the parents context from the child components?

I am using React 16 and OpenLayers 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I got it. I am using context, which I am aware is experimental but I am planning to break this into a seperate library/node module in the near future so I am happy with the risks involved.

Here is a fiddle (https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/fk250y38/) of the sample app working how I wanted it too. I have added two `ScaleLine` child components to help illustrate how it works.

Essentially I have taken Dane's comment about moving the `this.map` code to the constructor, I then use React's context API (getChildContext method) to make `this.map` available to the descendant's before using the `componentDidMount` lifecycle method to set the target DOM element for the map to display on.

I also found this (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lxq938kqIss) YouTube video really helpful, so thanks to the guys at 'ReactCasts' for that. It is worth watching their two part video series on context in React to get a well explained example of the plus' and minus' of the context API.

I hope this helps someone else in the future.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the `this.map` object via props to children. Also note that `componentDidMount` gets executed after render, so you might want to do the initializations inside constructor.

```
class Map extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
       // .........
        // Add map, base view and layer
    this.map = new ol.Map({
      target: 'map',
      layers: [this.baseLayer],
      view: this.baseView
    });

    //......
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    let childrenWithProps = React.Children.map(children, child =>
    React.cloneElement(child, { mapObject: this.map }));

    return (
      <div id="map">
        {childrenWithProps}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class ScaleLine extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    // Add scale line - not sure how to add to the parent context
    this.props.mapObject.addControl(new ol.control.ScaleLine({ units: this.props.units }));
  }

  render() {
    return '';
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. When I try this solution I get the mapObject of `undefined` in the child component.

Comment: Use `this.props.mapObject` to access the object. I've updated the answer

Comment: See https://jsfiddle.net/mcneela86/8xrhjt9t/ `this.props.mapObject` is `undefined`

Comment: Ok, sorry for taking so much time. You have initialized you `this.map` inside `componentDidMount` which is called **after** your render, and thus, it is undefined. Please do the initializations of `this.map` inside constructor.

Comment: Thanks again for the update, you are correct that the object get passed through when placed in the constructor but the doesn't render to the screen when using this method.